# How to remove blue glow from Sherlock action bar menu item?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Does anybody know how to remove this annoying blue glow that surrounds action bar menu item that is pressed?

[image]

Thanks,
Mladjo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can overwrite ...

```
android:actionBarItemBackground
```

... that defines a drawable resource for each action item's background. E.g.

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
</style>
```

Check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Note: if you want to support Android versions with API level less than 14 you have to include the [support package](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) (ABS) in your app. Afterwards you need to set the background for both  - Android standard and ABS:

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
</style>
```

Instead of a drawable you could also use a color, e.g.:

```
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@color/myColorDefinition</item>
```

**p.s.** ... or best, use a state drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Great answer. It's still wise to provide a state-list drawable so that the user knows the control is interactive and also so that people navigating using non-touch controls know when it's focused.