# how to highlight a menu item on selection?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

How to highlight menu item on selection, I tried modifying styles.xml with various attributes like `colorPressedHighlight`, `colorActivatedHighlight`, etc. Is there any way to keep the menu item focussed until other item is selected?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<style name="onPressedHighLight" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/OnPressed</item>
</style>
<color name="OnPressed" parent="AppBaseTheme">#FF0000</color>
```

Activity file:

```
setTheme(R.style.onPressedHighLight);
```

Comment: The answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705878/how-to-remove-blue-glow-from-sherlock-action-bar-menu-item/15706030#15706030 ... should help you; the question was slightly different put, but in the end it's the same issue

Comment: @André Thanks!! let me try to implement it!!

Answer (score 0):

Use selector for custom buttons. Search in google for more examples.
Here is [one](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/).

Comment: Its not button, its menu item, I tried it but was not feasible!!