# how to highlight action bar item select in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I am creating an app wherein I have three items in the action bar. I want that when I click on  one of the item, it should get highlighted.

I went through few examples available but concluded that I will have to create style using
ActionBar Style Generator tool.

I referred the following link.. but was not satisfied

[how to highlight a menu item on selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717356/how-to-highlight-a-menu-item-on-selection)

Is this the only way to go about?

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_bar_item_selector</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_blue" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_green" />
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

But the selection does not remain stagnant as it is for state_pressed and state_focused.

I want the item to remain highlighted till the user is on that activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am creating an app wherein I have three items in the action bar. I
>   want that when I click on one of the item, it should get highlighted.

I am not sure if the following will work properly:

Create two sets of icons for each of the menu items: one for the default look, the other highlighted (in whatever way you feel: change the color, change the background color etc.). Declare a global `Menu` variable to hold the menu item:

```
// Global variable // Not good practice, but needed in this case
Menu mainMenu;

....
....

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_name, menu);

    mainMenu = menu;

    return true;
}
```

In `onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)`:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    for (int i = 0; i < mainMenu.size(); i++) {

        // Set default icons
        if (mainMenu.getItem(i).getItemId() == R.id.action1) {
            mainMenu.getItem(i).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_default1);
        } else if (mainMenu.getItem(i).getItemId() == R.id.action2) {
            mainMenu.getItem(i).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_default2);
        } else if (.....) {
            .....
        }
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action1) {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_highlighted1);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action2) {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_highlighted2);
    } else if(.....) {
        .....
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

I guess you can fine-tune this by checking against `item.getItemId()` inside the `for-loop` itself.

Comment: this seems to be working perfectly. But is this the only way?

Comment: @anuja `this seems to be working perfectly. But is this the only way?`. This is more of a workaround in my opinion. I am not sure if another solution exists.

Answer (score 4):

More elegant way of handling the issue , is to simply have a boolean value that will check 
both states , If you are using the same drawable with different state colors , i will recommend
you to use the colorFilter method to apply to your drawables.

```
 private boolean mSomeValue = true; 

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // determine the menu item you want to highlight when selected
      switch(item.getItemId) {
           case yourItem : {
                if (mSomeValue) {
                    item.getIcon().setColorFilter(YourColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    mSomeValue = false;
                } else {
                    mSomeValue = true;
                    item.getIcon().setColorFilter(Default, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
            break; ...
           }
      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Comment: This works especially nice with the icons like    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"    and Color.DKGRAY to simulate a pressed state and clearColorFilter() for the normal state.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a theme and inherit the Action bar theme you want (for instance `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`), set the value of the `android:actionBarItemBackground` attribute to override the default one in the inheritted theme.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">custom_selector</item>
</style>
```

Comment: check my new answer !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i suggest you to create two different items in your `menu.xml`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_item1" 
   /> 


<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_item2"
    android:visible="false"
    />
```

Then, in the activity in which you want to highlight your item, override the on`onPrepareOptionsMenu` , use the `menu` paremeter to catch your desired item by using the `menu.findItem(R.id.your_item_id)`. And finally toggle the visibility of your items.

You will need to `refresh` your action bar items automatically by using `invalidateOptionsMenu`

Let me know if that helps !