# How might I keep a menuItem selected and highlighted in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have already looked at [how to highlight a menu item on selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717356/how-to-highlight-a-menu-item-on-selection) and I am also using [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). They are both essentially saying the same thing, from what I can tell. And neither does what I need. When I click on a menuItem. I want the item to **remain** highlight, until I click another one which would in turn become highlighted. How do I do that? I have even tried enabling a menuItem but seems to have no effect either. There seems to be no option to set a menu item as selected or focussed. So does anyone know how I might do this?

Comment: Use drawble , state selected and focused make ur menu selected !

Comment: @k0sh thanks for the tip. I know how to create a selector. But I don't know where I would place it. Would it be the parameter for `android:backgroundSplit` in my style sheet? That does not make much sense to me. So that's what I am stuck with the most.

Comment: Android: icon or background in style

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work. I would need to do it in code it seems. The problem being that when I switch activities, the menu is re-inflated. Which is not a problem as I could save the state and pass it in the intent as extra. But there seems to have no method for setting focus in the code.

Comment: btw, I use `android:actionBarItemBackground` for my selector, which seems to correct place.