# Disable background highlight color of menu item in android

Tags: android, background, selector, menuitem

I added an item (with icon and text) into my application's menu.

I have two images for the normal (nonpressed) state of the item and for the highlightened (pressed) state.

This is my menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
         android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
         android:title="New"
         android:icon="@drawable/menu_selector"
         android:id="@+id/add_channel"></item>-
</menu>
```

And this is the selector menu_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false"
           android:state_pressed="false"
           android:drawable="@drawable/new_channel" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/book"/>

    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/book" />
</selector>
```

But this is not enough for me. When I press the item, it changes the image it contains but also a green glow effect highlights in the background.

How can I disable or make invisible this glow effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove blue glow from Sherlock action bar menu item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705878/how-to-remove-blue-glow-from-sherlock-action-bar-menu-item)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove pressed effect on action bar home icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369749/remove-pressed-effect-on-action-bar-home-icon)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a layout with a ImageButton and a selector for its background to change the pressed state color. 
Select this layout at menu your item :
`android:actionLayout="@layout/item_layout"`

item_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_item_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

tab_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_button_background"/>
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_button_background_pressed" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_button_background"
     />
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_button_background"
     />
</selector>
```

tab_button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#9ec03b" />
</shape>
```

tab_button_background_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#dfff53" />
</shape>
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_channel"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/item_layout"
        android:title="New">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a click listener on the item you can put this code in the handler:

```
menuItem.setChecked(false);
```