# Remove pressed effect on action bar home icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

First, a few words about the app : minimum level is 16, I use a DrawerLayout (with the indicator) and have changed the background of my ActionBar.

When clicking on the home button to open the drawer, there is a blue pressed effect on both the image and the drawer indicator, that I'd like to remove. I tried setting `selectableItemBackground` in the styles to transparent, nearly everywhere I could think of, but that doesn't seem to change anything. Do anyone have a solution ?

Here is the image of this effect I'd like to remove :

[image: example image]

Here is the styles.xml part for the ActionBar I'm using :

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Bnp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_green</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Title</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

and finally the [drawable used for background](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ml6lwg51zcad6t/action_bar_green.9.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`selectableItemBackground` is close, but you need to use the `actionBarItemBackground` attribute instead.

For instance:

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

You should keep in mind that the system uses this attribute in the `ActivityChooserView` too, which is what the `ShareActionProvider` returns in `ActionProvider.onCreateActionView`.

To highlight all this, here are the results when you use `@android:color/holo_red_light` instead:

[image: Example]

Comment: I tried to add that to my action bar style, but the problem is still there. I added my styles.xml part in the question and the drawable used for background. Maybe this comes from the fact I used a DrawerLayout ?

Comment: @ValentinRocher You need to place `actionBarItemBackground` in your root theme, like my example.

Comment: Right, my bad, when using it in the root theme, it works all right, thanks a lot !